# A list of all asp controls for .net 4

Tags: asp.net, .net, servercontrols

I'm looking for a text list of all the ASP controls for .NET, ideally with accessible attributes.

Something like:

```
asp:Button - runat, visible, text, enabled, onclick
asp:Label - runat, visible, text, enabled, onclick
etc.
```

My intent is to use them in auto-complete with a text-editor.

Comment: Open up visual studio and expand the toolbox

Comment: I'm looking for them in a text list.

Comment: Have you tried the MSDN site? Google?

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_examples.asp

```
HTMLAnchor
HTMLButton
HTMLImage
HTMLInputbutton
HTMLInputCheckbox
HTMLInputHidden
HTMLInputImage
HTMLInputRadiobutton
HTMLTable
HTMLTextarea
AdRotator
Button
Calendar
Checkbox
CheckboxList
DataList
DropdownList
Hyperlink
Image
ImageButton
Label
LinkButton
Listbox
Literal
Panel
Radiobutton
RadiobuttonList
Repeater
Table
Textbox
XML
CompareValidator
CustomValidator
RangeValidator
RegularExpressionValidator
RequiredFieldValidator
Validationsummary
```